# mitmproxy - How to Get FULL Output File in Windows?

Tags: windows, mitmproxy

Just installed mitmproxy in Windows and it works great. The only problem is that there is no interactive user interface per the documentation. **If I copy the console text I do not see the full data in the requests like JSON/XML**. How can I get an output file with all the information for the requests?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `-dd` to display both headers and message contents. If you want to try out some alpha-quality software, you can also try mitmweb and open the webinterface on http://localhost:8081/.

Comment: Open a command line (File -> Command Line), then type `mitmdump -dd`.